# SSDT - Do not alter user permissions, but alter table permissions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

When publishing a database project, I would like to grant/revoke permissions to an object like a view or a table only, objects that are in-build definition. I do not want SSDT to take into consideration user permissions.

For example when removing a permission in a table file, I would want it to alter permission on objects in build only, but it also alters permissions on users too.

I would like:

```
REVOKE SELECT
ON OBJECT::[dbo].[myTable] TO [myRole] CASCADE
AS [dbo];
```

And I do not want:

```
REVOKE CONNECT TO [Domain\MyUser] CASCADE;
```

When I tick [x] Do not drop permissions, it takes away both, and when I include it in, it includes both types.

I have also ticked [x] Exclude users, but with no success.

Is there a way to do it or a possible workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a post-deploy script to get the exact behavior you describe.

Comment: So would you remove permissions from object definition files like table, and manage permissions through post - deployment scripts?

Comment: In general, no.  Generally I use double-abstraction to manage permissions.  Create database roles according to business functions.  Assign permissions to the role.  Assign all users to Windows/AD groups.  Add the groups as logins and users.  Add the groups as members of the appropriate database role.  Makes it easy to manage permissions and users independently.  This scheme also works well with post-deployment scripts, especially if you have different environments (e.g. dev, uat, qa, prod) with differing permission requirements.

Comment: OK, let's say I manage users outside of database project. How would you then add a select permission on a table/view ? Add it to the table/view file and create a post-deployment script? Or create a post-deployment script only but then the table definition would not reflect its permission in the file correctly?

Comment: Basically, do it in post deploy, leveraging double-abstraction.  Especially since I often work with projects deployable in different AD domains and security requirements.  My table defs contain no permission info.  For me, that reflects how SQL views objects and permissions.  They are different things and can (should?) be managed independently.

Comment: I've tended to handle permissions by granting them to roles rather than users. You put the users into the roles appropriate for what they need. This is probably the better way to handle it and then handle the users/roles outside of SSDT or use a separate script to add/remove users from roles.  I also tend to work with systems where the users are different in each environment so need to abstract those permissions anyway, but it's still easier to permiss with roles that do things.